# AngularJS: GroupBy then Sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I have a collection and im grouping it using lodash.js groupBy before displaying in the UI using ng-repeat

```
    var list = [{id:1,categoryId:1,name:test1},
                {id:2,categoryId:2,name:test2},
                {id:3,categoryId:12,name:test12}]

    vm.myList= _.groupBy(list,function (j) { return j.categoryId; });

    console.debug(vm.myList) // this shows the correct ordering!!!
```

Now when im displaying it using ng-repeat it messes up the ordering

```
<div ng-repeat="(categoryId, details) in vm.myList| orderBy: 'categoryId'>
        {{ categoryId }}
</div>
```

this displays

```
1
12
2
```

how can I make it to display

```
1
2
12
```

I'm trying something like this but no luck

```
<div ng-repeat="(categoryId, details) in vm.myList| orderBy: 'parseInt(categoryId)'>
            {{ categoryId }}
    </div>
```

UPDATE! I found out that this is not an issue in Angular 1.4.x . Unfortunately, we are using old version Angular 1.3.x

Comment: @elclanrs still no luck. it sort it as string

Comment: @elclanrs: that's not how angular's `orderBy` works

Comment: when i `console.debug(vm.myList)` its in correct order, but in `ng-repeat` it messes up the ordering, even if i remove the `orderBy`

Comment: Can you try as `orderBy: -'parseInt(categoryId)`

Comment: the orderBy method from angular does the order for strings not integers so a workaround is to sort it in js code then to display. Also you can send a function to the orderby as I can remember.

Comment: @user2232187 yeah actually, its already sorted out in JS, but the ng-repeat messes it out

Comment: your 3rd `id` should be `id:3` instead of  ` 1 `{id:1,categoryId:12,name:test12}`

Comment: General note, don't be too quick with using arbitrary javascript (here `parseInt`) in angular expressions. Angular does not use eval or anything, it parses the expression with it's own parser and so you're not always guaranteed to get the result you might expect.

Comment: @Altius thats just a typo

Comment: `vm.myList` is object? if so, than _orderBy_ not working with object, and also ngRepeat - get key as string and sorted it

Comment: @LincAbela since you already sort it in js you don't need the order bay again :P

Comment: what angular version you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, `orderBy` filter working only with arrays, so if you try pass object to it, would be returned passed object as is.

second, with [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular 1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)
>
> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting.
>
> If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such as [toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter)

So for solving your issue just convert your groupped object to array, and sort it as you want.